# How to mock jersey controllers like MVCMock of spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I'm using spring MVC boot application with jersey REST service insted the one that spring provided.

Is there any way to mock the controllers like MVCMock is doing? if now, what it the best way to test the controllers? seemd like i must have the application up and runing to run the test which it is sound abit occurred

Answer (score 0):

There is a Testing framework for Jersey named [Jersey test](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). You should use that.

Comment: With this framword i could run the tests without running the spring server  on tomcat?